# Facebook comment box not working in Joomla articles, works in K2

Tags: joomla2.5, facebook-comments, joomla-k2

We primarily use K2 for content on our site, but it doesn't have a working pagebreak function while Joomla does. We just started using Joomla articles and I'm trying to match the design between both. The one thing that's hanging me up is the facebook comment box.

The facebook comments works in K2 but doesn't in Joomla articles, even though the code is the same. 
This is the code I'm using right after the body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=354401011334700";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And this is what I have for the comment box in the article:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"
data-width="450" data-num-posts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

The weird thing is that if you look at the source code, it's there. It just won't display it. 
Any thoughts?

Btw, we're using Joomla! v2.5.8.

If you'd like to see the pages (comment box supposed to appear after AddThis buttons):

K2 aritcle – http://sciality.com/the-feed/robot-weight-loss-coach-helps-humans-slim-down.html

Joomla article – http://sciality.com/SCIFI/top-10-most-anticipated-scifi-movies-of-2013.html

Answer (score 0):

Have used available plugins to work with native joomla artcles and it works just fine. for Instance, the Joomla Sp Comments works well with Native articles and even provide room for moderation on the articles.